# iOS InAppPurchases with Phonegap 2.5

Tags: iphone, html, in-app-purchase, cordova

I'm currently implementing a HTML5 app for android and iOS. Now my next business is to get the in app purchases working.

I'm using Cordova 2.5, building with Xcode 4.6.2.
As plugin for the InAppPurchases I use https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

I have registered an new version of my application with all inApp products ready to sale.

If i use a emulator i can get the data for a product. It shows a popup to purchase the item with the correct price. Then it asks for the Apple Id. I register with the created Test-Users. Then the app crashes with the error following error message:

```
2013-04-17 18:10:16.319 App[23553:c07] error 0 Cannot connect to iTunes Store
2013-04-17 18:10:16.319 App[23553:c07] state: PaymentTransactionStateFailed
2013-04-17 18:10:16.319 App[23553:c07] js: plugins.inAppPurchaseManager.updatedTransactionCallback.apply(plugins.inAppPurchaseManager, [
  "PaymentTransactionStateFailed",
  0,
  "Cannot connect to iTunes Store",
  "",
  "",
  ""
])
```

I don't understand why it says, that he cannot connect to the iTunes store. Because the data is already loaded from there.

Has anyone an idea what i could do to get it working?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok. I fixed it. The first thing I did was waiting, not changing anything and returning to the project 24 hours later already reduced some issues. Then I downloaded a free application from the App Store with the test user. And i nearly reached the point where it could work... And then i switched to another version of the plugin: https://github.com/usmart/InAppPurchaseManager-EXAMPLE. Guess what? It works right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I fixed it. The first thing I did was waiting, not changing anything and returning to the project 24 hours later already reduced some issues. Then I downloaded a free application from the App Store with the test user. And i nearly reached the point where it could work... And then i switched to another version of the plugin: github.com/usmart/InAppPurchaseManager-EXAMPLE. Guess what? It works right now.